# Uber Ride widget Error

Tags: uber-api

This is regarding the issue we are facing today while a user is trying to access the uber rides widget via our App.

Current Process:

1. User Launches our App and navigates to ina app Uber Page.
2. He/She is asked to Link an uber profile. (We use Oauth process to get his access token). Scopes used to generate the token are “profile, ride_widgets, history, history_lite, history_fare, places”.
3. Once we have the token and if he wishes to book an uber ride we land him to https://components.uber.com/rides?access_token= in the InApp browser. Since few days we have started getting this error for all tokens. Let us know if something is missing here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is expected, the ride widget is deprecated. Per that documentation:

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/widget/introduction

"This product is deprecated and will no longer be supported on May 31st, 2018. If you are starting a new project you should use deep links to m.uber.com. See the migration guide on how to link to the latest Uber rider experience."

Comment: Hi Kyle, The thing is, it works when we have extra scope ("request") added in the scope list while generating the access token. So if its deprecated then it should not work at all. I requested for full privileged access for that scope to which uber support team rejected.

Comment: The widget is deprecated. Please use deeplinks into the Uber app or m.uber.com. Thanks!